# Apply DISTINCT before WHERE

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table like this:

```
model_id | object_id | date_modified
1        | 123       | NULL
1        | 123       | 2012-12-11 16:55:21
1        | 456       | 2012-12-11 16:52:21
1        | 789       | NULL
```

I want to return the object_ids that have not been modified.  Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
SELECT object_id from Table WHERE date_modified IS NULL
```

This returns 123 and 789, I only want 789.

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_id from Table WHERE date_modified IS NULL
```

This also returns 123 and 789 as the DISTINCT clause is applied after the WHERE filters the results.

Is there a way to achieve this with a single query or should I just return a list of distinct object_ids and loop through and filter programmatically?

Comment: What rule are you using to determine which record to return? I assume you are grouping by model_id so is it fair to assume you want to retrieve the record with the highest object_id that has a null date_modified field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT object_id from Table GROUP BY object_id HAVING MAX(date_modified) IS NULL
```

Comment: Brilliant - this one answers the question, _"I want to return the object_ids that have not been modified."_

Answer (score 0):

A nested query will help.  The inner query selects all object_ids that have been modified, and then the outer query selects all records with a null date but for which the object_id is not in the modified list.

```
SELECT object_id FROM table
  WHERE date_modified IS NULL AND object_id NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM table
      WHERE date_modified IS NOT NULL
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d98ea/10)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.object_id 
from Table1 t
WHERE t.object_id NOT IN (SELECT t1.object_id 
                          FROM Table1 t1
                          WHERE t1.date_modified IS NOT NULL)
```

Result:

```
| OBJECT_ID |
-------------
|       789 |
```